# How do you return the k smallest elements of an array using Mergesort?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, sorting

I'd like to create a modified mergesort algorithm to return the *k* smallest elements of an array. The mergesort algorithm below sorts an unordered array of size *n*. How do I modify the algorithm so that it returns the *k* smallest elements of the array?

```
A = [1...n]

Mergesort (A,p,r)  //start with p = 1 and r = A.length
  if p < r
    q = floor((p + r)/2)
    Mergesort (A,p,q)
    Mergesort (A,q + 1,r)
    Merge-Sort (A,p,q,r)

Merge-Sort (A,p,q,r)
  n1 = q - p + 1
  n2 = r - q
  Let L[1,2,..,n1+1] and R[1,2,..,n2+1] be new arrays
  for i = 1 to n1
    L[i] = A[p + i - 1]
  for j = 1 to n2
    R[j] = A[q + j]
  L[n1 + 1] = (an infinitely big number)
  R[n2 + 1] = (an infinitely big number)
  i = 1
  j = 1
  for m = p to r
    if L[i] <= R[j]
      A[m] = L[i]
      i = i + 1
    else
      A[m] = R[j]
      j = j + 1
```

Comment: What is the intended time complexity ? because merge-sort is $O(nlogn)$ where $n$ is the number of elements, you can simply sort and take the kth element.

Comment: @sai_preet I think time complexity should be no slower than O(n logn). Not sure if I misunderstood, but I need to take the the k smallest elements, no the kth one.

Comment: It doesn't change the time complexity at all, since $n<k$ it will take $O(n log n)$ to sort, then $O(K)$ to get the smallest one, which is at worst $O(n)$, so after the sort the whole run time is still just $O(nlogn)$

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the code.  This site is about concepts, algorithms, principles, etc. behind computer science, not about code or implementation.  As far as I can tell, you just copy-pasted pseudocode for standard mergesort into your question.  That is not helpful and adds no value.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be a select, partition then sort technique.
First you use the [Median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm to find the $k$th smallest element, this takes $O(n)$ time.

After that has been found you partition your list, partition using this $k$th element as a pivot. This takes $O(n)$ time.

Now if you want the result sorted you can use mergesort on these $k$ elements, taking $O(k\log k)$ time, at worst case if $n=k$ then this whole process runs in $O(n\log n)$ time, the expected case is less but depends on $k$.

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem, but not an answer to the question as you don't use Mergesort.

Answer (score 0):

What if in Merge Step you only merge first K elements ? 
That way you should have  O(k*logN) time complexity !

Comment: Better to provide more details and justifications.

Comment: What about the recursive calls?

Comment: @Raphael : Recursive call we go to a maximum level of log N (as it goes in normal mergesort ) but the merge step will always just merge the first K elements, which would give you the smallest K elements at the end of the algorithm.

Comment: So, you need to go to log N level to sort two adjacent elements. But, in Merge Step, you have two sorted array of same size say m. Now, you only need to merge until you get first K elements as rest of the elements of the two arrays will definitely not be in the answer.